# Ignoring bracketed sections in a regex match

Tags: regex, perl

Right now I have this regex:

```
/regular(\[[a-z]*\])* expression/i
```

which correctly matches this string:

```
Regular[AECC][XVK] Expression
```

but fails to match these:

```
R[AECC]egular [XVK]Expression
R[ABC]egular Expression
Regular[xx] Expressio[]n
```

How can I match *all* of the above with a single regex?

Comment: given that regexes are intended to find things in "random" positions, yes it's possible. and you can use lookarounds to say "find randomly positioned X that is (not) followed/preceded by Y"

Comment: I would just write a regex that removes all `\[[a-z]*\]*` from a string and then another regex to match `regular expression`.

Comment: Questions which ask "is it possible" are not very helpful. The answer is "Yes", but this isn't the place to have people write code for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
/
   r (?:\[[a-z]*\])?
   e (?:\[[a-z]*\])?
   g (?:\[[a-z]*\])?
   ...
   i (?:\[[a-z]*\])?
   o (?:\[[a-z]*\])?
   n
/ix
```

or

```
my $pat = join '(?:\\[[a-z]*\\])?', map quotemeta, split //, 'regular expression';
my $re = qr/$pat/i;
/$re/
```

or

```
s/\[[a-z]*\]//ig;
/regular expression/i
```

Comment: Seems the first one will do, but I will change the non-capture group to capture group as it is matching string only and remain unchanged. Thank you.